# How to play local video in HTML5 using video path

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, converters, video-player

**Without using input file please help**

```html
<video width="350" height="240" controls loop>
  <source src="/storage/emulated/0/Html/Vid/video.mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? [Validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Comment: i assume u wanna play a video from cilents filesystem, so, If u start url with, `/` it will resolve under ur domain. U need to use file protocol `file://` which is forbidden with err `Security Error: Content at moz-nullprincipal:{...} may not load or link to file:///storage/emulated/0/Html/Vid/video.mp4.`

Answer (score 0):

> play local video (...) without input file

- locally in your browser - use hardcoded path - direct to the file - as you did
- if you want to your on-line page will secretly access somebody's local files - you can not do this, it is not possible - this aren't your files and they aren't public

Locally, without server - you have better tools in OS, and others to install.
Html on-line or not `<input type="file">` is good and safe solution.

Code is good. If doesn't work for you:

- check the path and file name-extension against typos
- test with another file - this one can be broken
- use better browser (read: your ancient browser doesn't support `.mp4` or `<video>`)

Comment: How to convert video path to url ?

Comment: If you ask a question - start a new question, not a comment to accidental post. Follow the rules please - Q&A not a forum